# Disabling git packing in libgit2

Tags: git, libgit2

I am using `libgit2` and try to find a way to disable packing/zipping of git objects. Does `git` or `libgit` have a configuration to completely disable that?

In specific, I would need a full copy of the commited object in the `./git/objects` directory.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can disable packing and zipping of git objects because that's the core way git works.

But libgit2 have something that is called [custom object backend](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Appendix-B%3A-Embedding-Git-in-your-Applications-Libgit2#_advanced_functionality) that allows you to write your own way to store the files.

Comment: This is correct.  Out of the box, libgit2 speaks to the object database the way git does, with loose objects or packed objects.  To avoid any compression and just get raw data, you'll need to write a custom backend that takes that raw data and just writes it wherever you want it to go.